# Location of Liquibase DATABASECHANGELOG Tables

Tags: liquibase

I've seen how to rename the DATABASECHANGELOG tables but what I'm looking to do is to have them created in one database for each server and then deploy to the other databases on that server. We are using Liquibase on MSSQL and Sybase databases and executing via command line.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

I've had the same thought before as well.  That's just not how it's done at my current shop :)

You're looking for these options:

```
--liquibaseCatalogName=<name>              The name of the catalog with the
                                            liquibase tables
--liquibaseSchemaName=<name>               The name of the schema with the
                                            liquibase tables
```

Doc here: http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/command_line.html.
However, `--liquibaseCatalogName` is not documented, but it does appear as an option when checking the command line options via `liquibase --help`.  In your case, I believe "Catalog" equates to a Database in MSSQL and Sybase.